# A Generic User Auth for Multiple domains and sub-domains

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, openid

I'm currently working on a project that has other projects (mini-projects) connected to it. The project is developed using `CodeIgniter PHP framework` and the mini-projects are developed in `different technologies`.

A simple example could be a `main site` that is hosted in its domain `(www.mainsite.com)`. The other mini-projects are hosted in individual sub-domains like forum `(forum.mainsite.com)` and blog `(blog.mainsite.com)`.

The user will be directed to the same authentication server whether he is on the `mainsite` or `forum` or `blog`. He will be directed to the same `Login form` and `Registration form`.

[image]

Taking that scenario into consideration, what approach has to be taken to have a single login credential (username and password) to be used for the main project and mini-projects?

Some resources I came across:

- [OpenID](http://openid.net/)
- [OAuth](http://oauth.net/)

Comment: I have been looking for something similar. I came across this solution http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/ but I havent tried it yet

Comment: @VitorBari the link you gave me is similar to what OpenID does. It would be better you suggest on how I can configure my own openid-server